# How do I create Azure AD Tenant through code

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

**Can we create a new azure active directory through PowerShell. I have searched and couldn't find much information? ** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this functionality does not currently exist.  I struggle to imagine it ever existing since the process of creating a tenant is so complex and requires the acceptance of various agreements.

Answer (score 2):

NO, You cannot create Azure Active Directory tenant using PowerShell. I do not think, you will need to create an Azure Active Directory. It is already created and managed by Microsoft. What you create is a tenant within Azure Active Directory.

However you can perform the following [actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) with Powershell once you have the Azure AD.

Comment: Thank you Sajeetharan. Sorry I was meaning a tenant, thank you for pointing.